# Three level list in PYTHON

Tags: python

I am stuck in Python. I need to create and parse a 3-level list.
For example, a list inside a list inside a list.

2 levels are working for me but going to the third is so much confusion please help

```
l= [1,5,6,7,8,['a','b','c','d']]
a= ['name 1','name 2',l]

for i in a:
   if type(i) == type([]):
      for j in i:
         print(j, end=' ')
      for k in j:
         if type(j) == type([]):
             print('non')


else:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to print and what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Can you post the exact output you're looking for?

Comment: I need to print all the text.
currently it is printing like this: name 1 , name 2 , 1 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 ['a' ,' b' , 'c' , 'd' ]

i want it to print simply: name 1 , name 2 , 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 , a , b , c ,d

without any bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are just missing an indent:

```
l= [1,5,6,7,8,['a','b','c','d']]
a= ['name 1','name 2',l]

for i in a:
   if type(i) == list:
      for j in i:
         if type(j) == list:
             for k in j:
                 print(k, end=' ')
         else:
             print(j, end=' ')


   else:
       print(i, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in a:
    if type(i) is list: ## If i is a list
        for j in i:
            if type(j) is list: ## If j is a list
                for k in j:
                    print(k)
            else:
                print(j)
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but code-only answers are discouraged, especially when it's unclear what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned we don't know what is exactly your purpose so it is hard to help you.

However, here are some tips:

- Elements in `for` loop shall indented
- For checking types, you can use `isinstance`
- You can use new lines to increase visibility of the initial variable
- Give better names to your variables

A code solving your issue could look like this

```
nested_list = [
    'name1',
    'name2',
    [
        1, 3, 5, 7,
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    ]
]

for i in nested_list:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        for j in i:
            # Do something with j
            if isinstance(j, list):
                for k in j:
                    # Do something with k, like for example
                    print("%s ==> %s ==> %s" % (i, j, k))
    else:
        # Do something else with i, like for example
        print("I: %s" % i)`
```

An easier way if you just need to print the list is to use the module `pprint`. See [**PythonModuleOfTheWeek**](https://pymotw.com/2/pprint/) for a great tutorial.

You just have to do the following:

```
import pprint

nested_list = [
    'name1',
    'name2',
    [
        1, 3, 5, 7,
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    ]
]

pprint.pprint(nested_list)
```